# Why I'm "losing" a function with the spread operator on window.localStorage?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to "extend" `window.localStorage` with some custom methods, returning an object of shape `EnhancedStorageType`, with additional members.

Before the spread operator, `storage.clear` is defined... but it's "lost" right after the spread.

```typescript
type EnhancedStorageType = Storage & {
  getAllItems: () => { [key: string]: any },
};

export const useEnhancedStorage(): EnhancedStorageType {
  const storage = window.localStorage;

  console.log(storage.clear); // OK here: ƒ clear() { [native code] }

  const store = {
    ...storage,
    getItems(...keys: string[]) {
      return keys.map(key => this.getItem(key));
    },
  };

  console.log(store.clear); // KO here: undefined

  return store;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need such a circus? You could use `_proto_`

Comment: @AzizHakberdiev he might not want to pollute prototypal chain. as it will make it available everywhere. and polluting it is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

don't spread it directly assign it
let trial = window.localStorage
const answer = {newStorage:trial,someOtherProperty:"property"}

answer.newStorage.clear() // it is perfectly ok here
[image]